# How can I call a specific function inside a jquery init method

Tags: jquery

I am using the init method to run several functions on page load. From a click event I need to access a specific function and not run all of them again, for example test2(). How can I do this?

```
var widget = function() {

    var test = function() {  return 'test ok'; }
    var test2 = function() {     return 'test 2 ok'; }

    return {
        init: function() { test(); test2(); }
    };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  widget.init(); });

$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
    test2();
});
```

Comment: define the `var test2` function before the `var widget` init. Then you will be able to call it from outside the `widget` function. Please have a look at variable scope in JS. Then it will all be clear.

Comment: great that works.. is there a way to access the function without declaring it global?

Comment: in the past I used some code but i cant remember... it was something like this widget.init(test2(),{}) ...

Comment: why is declaring it global an issue? I will add an answer with my other comment

Comment: no issue just wondering if possible.

Comment: I never personally had the chance to try smth like that. never needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the function you want to call in the `widget` init function and on click is declared globally. Something like this:

```
var test2 = function() {     return 'test 2 ok'; }

var widget = function() {

    var test = function() {  return 'test ok'; }


    return {
        init: function() { test(); test2(); }
    };

}();

$(document).ready(function() {  widget.init(); });

$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
    test2();
});
```

This is a great starting point to understand the scopes correctly: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Comment: I added var test2; outside the widget . not the complete function